# MirageJS not finding route - VueJS

Tags: vue.js, mocking, frontend, miragejs

We are trying MirageJS in our VueJS application and in a login screen, it makes a request `post("auth/signin")`. The api url is like `http://localhost/v1` and it is configured in Axios instance as baseUrl. The MirageJS server routes has `this.namespace="v1"` (I tried `/v1`, `/v1/`, `v1/`),
and `this.post("/auth/signin", cb(schema, request))`.

When I make the request I get this error
[image]

Vue code

[image]

Where `http` is an instance of axios

[image]

What could it be?

[image]

Comment: Hm, looks like your Vue app is making a request but just to `localhost` with no port specified. I'm guessing your Vue CLI dev server is serving on some port, say `localhost:3000`. Can you share the Vue code that is actually making the ajax request?

Comment: (by default Mirage route handlers attach themselves to the current port, something like `localhost:3000`. You could try setting the `urlPrefix` to just `http://localhost` and see if that helps https://miragejs.com/api/classes/server/#url-prefix but I think your app code is the problem.)

Comment: It's solved. I can't tell exactly why, but I used urlPrefix passing my api url with port and it did work now. Thank you.

Comment: Next debugging step is to remove `namespace` and write out fully qualified domain name in the handler: `this.post('http://localhost/v1/auth', (schema, request) =>`.